# Laravel Validation required this or that

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I need to validate a request account_type if it is either 'Personal' or 'Organizational'
So that i can validate other field by required if account_type,personal.Heres the code that i have tried.

```
        'account_type' => 'required|options:PERSONAL,ORGANIZATIONAL',
        'per_client_name' => 'required_if:account_type,PERSONAL|string',
        'per_street' => 'required_if:account_type,PERSONAL',
        'per_address' => 'required_if:account_type,PERSONAL',
        'org_name' => 'required_if:account_type,ORGANIZATIONAL',
        'org_type' => 'required_if:account_type,ORGANIZATIONAL',
        'org_cont_name' => 'required_if:account_type,ORGANIZATIONAL'
```

Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateOptions does not exist. **This is the error that i got.**

Comment: in:PERSONAL,ORGANIZATIONAL

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in

Comment: Yes, you can use 'account_type' => 'required|in:PERSONAL,ORGANIZATIONAL',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only have these 2 options **(PERSONAL,ORGANIZATIONAL)**, then use `in` instead of `options`. Like this :

```
'account_type' => 'required|in:PERSONAL,ORGANIZATIONAL',
```

It works for me.